# How to save/load progress?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Suppose I have a program, with let's say - a dictionary, that the user updates, changes and stuff like that. Now, I want to save that dictionary in a file, so in the next time he runs the program, he can continue where he stopped.

What is the right way to/how would you accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: How about a simple text file you write to upon each change?

Comment: When you say "dictionary", do you mean `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be to serialize the Dictionary object itself to a file, in either a custom format, XML, or simply a binary representation and then deserialize it when the application loads, but this breaks down with multiple users.

One of the most common approaches to persisting data is in a database.

Apologies if this answer is vague, but the solution really depends on the needs of your application. Maybe a simple text file is sufficient, or maybe you do need something more robust, such as a database.

There are several free database options out there: [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx), [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com), [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) just to name a few.

Comment: I have tried using stuff like XML, it was a pain, but using a database is a great solution. thank you so much.

Comment: For single file save/load SQLite is most suitable among listed above.

Answer (score 3):

I would just serialize the dictionary since that's what the app is using.

Assuming that you have a `Dictionary<string, string>` here the serialize method I'd use:

```
var entries = 
    dictionary
        .Select(kvp =>
            new XElement(
                "entry",
                new XAttribute("key", kvp.Key),
                new XAttribute("value", kvp.Value)));


var xd = new XDocument(new XElement("dictionary", entries));

xd.Save(@"C:\filename.xml");
```

And then to bring it back from disk:

```
var dictionary =
    XDocument
        .Load(@"C:\filename.xml")
        .Root
        .Elements("entry")
        .ToDictionary(
            x => x.Attribute("key").Value,
            x => x.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Pretty easy, huh?

Answer (score 2):

So, a dictionary *could* be a pretty large thing and loading it all up in memory isn't probably the answer.  I'd probably utilize some sort of DB to hold it - sqlite or something like that would work.  It would be pretty straightforward to track the last thing the user used in a table entry and the dictionary entries as well.  Particularly for a dictionary the DB solution works nicely because it allows for things like links to other entries, etc.  Doing this in some flat file or even in XML is probably the wrong approach if it is of any appreciable size.